# form.getRecord() is undefind. Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

In my application I use the `Ext.form.Panel` component. In the panel set the selected entry from the tree using `loadRecord(record)`

```
...
showDataFields: function(view, record, item, index, event) {       
        var panel = view.up('tabpanel');
        var formfield   = panel.down('form');        
        formfield.loadRecord(record);
    },

....
```

I get an entry to send data to the store

```
...

saveUserData: function(button, e) {
        var values;
        var panel    = button.up('actionform'),
            form   = panel.down('form');
        record = form.getRecord();
        console.log(record)// value undefined. Why ?      
    },

...
```

How to get a record?

Link to my [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2oa6) app  the form is in the file app/view/ActionFormTree.js

The `showDataFields` and `saveUserData` methods are in app/controller/MainController.js

thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are getting your `form` component using `button.up('actionform')` and then after again you are using `panel.down('form')`. So in this case you getting inner `form` of `form` component. See below screenshot for better understanding (see selected dom element)

[image]

So you don't need to use down selector because you already getting `form` component using `button.up('actionform')`.

**Code Snippet**

```
saveUserData: function(button, e) {

    var values, form = button.up('actionform'),
        record = form.getRecord();

    console.log(record)
},
```

You can check here with working [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2oad).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your design correctly, what I think is the problem is how you reference your form.

```
saveUserData: function(button, e) {

    var values;
    var panel  = button.up('tabpanel'),
        form   = panel.down('form');
    // Or, because button is on your form:
    // var form = button.up('form');

    record = form.getRecord();
    console.log(record)// value undefined. Why ?

    //store = this.getUserTreeStoreStore('UserTreeStore');
    //values = form.getValues();
    //id = form.getRecord().get('id');

},
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer works for me. Why is it necessary to go up to the tabpanel?

Comment: @Ambasador You dont need to go up to '`tabpanel` in this case. Your button is on your form, so I think that `var form = button.up('actionform');` will be enough in this case.

Answer (score 0):

better is to assign the itemId property to your form panel and use getValues() function

```
var formpanel = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('form[itemId=your_form_itemId_here]')[0];
var form = formpanel.getForm();//this gets all the fields inside the form 
//no to fetch the record or form field values
var record = form.getValues();
```

this is Convenient function for fetching the current values of each field in the form. ...